# MessageBox, lock and System.Windows.Forms.Timer problem in C#

Tags: c#, locking

I believe I have a misunderstanding about either how a `lock` works or how the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` works in C#.

So I made a simple Windows Forms Application (.NET Framework) and I added a `Timer` and a `Button` to the `Form` from the Toolbox. The `Button` starts the `Timer` when clicked, and the `Timer` enters a `lock` on a dummy object and blocks it on the `Tick` event. For the `Button`'s `Click` event I have the following method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

And for the `Timer`'s `Tick` event I have this method:

```
readonly object lockObj = new object();

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock (lockObj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Entered the lock!");
        MessageBox.Show("Exiting the lock...");
    }
}
```

Everything else is left to default and there is no additional code.

I expected this program to show a single `MessageBox` with the text `"Entered the lock!"`, then after I close it and also the following one with the message `"Exiting the lock..."` I thought the lock would be released and a queued up Tick event if any would acquire the lock, the process reapeating. Instead, the `"Entered the lock!"` `MessageBox` keeps opening multiple times without having to close it, as if every `Tick` event call enters the lock even if nobody releases it.

I tried to replicate this in a Console Application but with no luck. I'd appreciate a hint about what causes this problem so I know where to look into it.

Alternative code you can test in a Windows Forms Application:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lock_Test_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Timer timer1;

        readonly object lockObj = new object();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Button button1 = new Button();
            button1.Location = new Point(100, 100);
            button1.Size = new Size(187, 67);
            button1.Text = "button1";
            button1.Click += button1_Click;
            Controls.Add(button1);

            timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Entered the lock!");
                MessageBox.Show("Exiting the lock...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The lock is used to prevent multiple processes executing the code at the same time.   So the lock locks when entering the block of code and releases the lock when exiting.  When a second process enters the block it is put to sleep until the first process exits the block.

Comment: Use `System.Timers.Timer` instead and code will work as you expected

Comment: Problem is `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` ... and the way how it works (message based WM_TIMER)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms.Timer` dispatches its events via a windows message loop.

`MessageBox.Show` shows a messagebox and then pumps the windows message loop as a nested loop. This can include dispatching more events for a timer.

Since only a single thread (the UI thread) is involved, and `lock` is reentrant, that's why you get multiple message boxes shown.

Comment: That seems to be the case, thank you for your answer. I tried to block the thread instead and no more MessageBoxes were shown.